# MySQL does not use index, does full table scan instead

Tags: mysql, query-performance, execution-plan, mysql-8.0, explain

**EDIT**: See further developments below.

---

I have an InnoDB table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `app_id` CHAR(27) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` CHAR(27) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs',
    `level_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `item_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `user_addr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `owner_addr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `reward` DECIMAL(10,5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `item_addr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `client_replay_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `processed_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `flags` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `owner_batch_id` CHAR(27) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs',
    `user_batch_id` CHAR(27) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `item_date_idx` (`item_id`, `date`),
    INDEX `owner_batch_id` (`owner_batch_id`),
    INDEX `user_batch_id` (`user_batch_id`),
    INDEX `flags` (`flags`),
    INDEX `owner_idx` (`owner_addr`),
    INDEX `level_reward_idx` (`date`, `item_id`, `app_id`, `level_id`),
    INDEX `user_balance_idx` (`user_addr`, `item_id`, `flags`),
    INDEX `owner_user_flags_idx` (`user_addr`, `owner_addr`, `flags`),
    INDEX `flags_date_idx` (`flags`, `date`)
) COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci';
```

This table has **~14 million rows**. I have a `SELECT` query using the `flags` and `date` columns. Despite having a composite index specifically for those columns (`flags_date_idx`) the query plan shows a full table scan instead:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM data WHERE flags&3=0 AND `date`>= '2022-06-19' AND `date` < '2022-07-04';
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data            | NULL       | ALL  | level_reward_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 14017708 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Index hints don't help either:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM data USE INDEX(flags_date_idx) WHERE flags&3=0 AND `date`>= '2022-06-19' AND `date` < '2022-07-04';
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data            | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 14018064 |    11.11 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,02 sec)
```

As it stands, this query can take up to several minutes to return, depending on the date range. How can I avoid a full table scan here?

---

**EDIT:** The problem was the bitwise query `flags&3=0`, which made it impossible to use any index because MySQL has to do a calculation for every row. Replacing it with `flags NOT IN (1,2,3)` (the possible values for this column) resolved the issue. See comments, and these SO answers [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352435/879047)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560514/mysql-doesnt-use-indexes-when-query-over-bit-field-using-bitwise-functions#comment3731757_3560514).

**EDIT 2:** As suggested by Rick James' answer, I tried grabbing the `id`s first and then using them to retrieve the columns:

```
mysql> explain SELECT b.* FROM ( SELECT id FROM data WHERE flags&3=0 AND date>= '2022-06-19' AND date < '2022-07-04' ) AS ids JOIN data AS b USING(id);
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type   | possible_keys            | key            | key_len | ref                          | rows     | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data            | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,level_reward_idx | flags_date_idx | 7       | NULL                         | 14263666 |    50.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b               | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY        | 8       | data.id                      |        1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0,04 sec)
```

Now it actually uses the correct index, but judging by `rows` it still scans the whole table. I'm confused.

Comment: How limiting is the flag column? In other words, how many rows are returned if you remove the date conditions from the where clause. Also, you have several similar indexes. Try consolidating several of those.

Comment: It's pretty limiting. `flags&3=0` returns ~250K rows out of 14 million.

Comment: Guessing the `&3` is the problem here. As a test, try `flags=0` or `flags IN ([series of integers where &3 yields 0])` and see if that helps. Or try creating a new column for `flags&3` and index that.

Comment: @barrycarter you're right! `flags=0` and `flags NOT IN (1,2,3)` both use the correct index. So, it seems MySQL simply doesn't support using indexes when querying with bitwise operators.

Comment: @DuruCanCelasun Think of an index as just an ordered list of the values, how would you effectively search that ordered list to get all the values which when bitwise anded with 3 give you 0? You would have to have an index on this expression instead for that to work, but you might as well just have a column per thing you are flagging, and index the ones that you would need to filter on (and would provide enough selectivity to be useful). You might be okay with just an index on `date` depending on how selective that range is.

Comment: @AndrewSayer that makes sense. I've found a few more DBA questions supporting that argument. I'll update the OP.

Comment: Are the `CHAR(27)` fields really fixed length?  Do they really need utf8mb4 (at 4 bytes per character)?

Comment: @RickJames they are fixed length, but no, they don't really need mb4, that's just unintentionally inherited from the table's collation.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the "&" operator, here are a couple of tips:

- Since you have `INDEX(flags, date)`, `DROP` the redundant `INDEX(flags)`.  (I have found cases where the shorter index is picked even when the wider one would be better.)
- Find the ids, *then* find the rest of the columns.  This can be especially efficient if the table is much bigger than RAM.

  ```
  SELECT b.*
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM data
               WHERE flags&3=0
                 AND `date`>= '2022-06-19'
                 AND `date` < '2022-07-04'
         ) AS ids
    JOIN data AS b  USING(id)
  ```

Provide the `EXPLAIN` for that query.  I would expect the derived table (subquery) to say "Using index" meaning that it was performed entirely using the index's BTree, which is much smaller than the data's BTree.  Hence faster.  Then the JOIN does 250K lookups via the PK.

Regardless, 250K rows takes a long time.

Comment: Subquery was a good idea! I added the results to the OP. Now it uses the index, but still seems to scan the entire table (rows = ~14M). Any idea why?

Comment: See if `INDEX(date, flags)` is any faster.  The Optimizer has no technique for avoiding checking all flags.  Bitwise operations are not "sargeable".

Comment: Right, putting `date` first would probably reduce the rows that need to be tested against the bitwise condition. Still, it won't be as fast as replacing the bitwise check with `flags NOT IN (...)`.